# content of div disappears after submitting

Tags: jquery

I modified the content of a div element on my page with jQuery and inserted content from different page like this:

**Page where content is inserted**

```
<?php include('../includes/overall/overallHeader.php'); ?>

<section class="content-header">
    <h1>Einsatzliste</h1>
</section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            var $sidebarNavigationList = $('#sidebarNavigationList');
            $($sidebarNavigationList).find('a').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#mainContent').load('incidents.php')
            });
        });
    </script>

<section class="content">
    <div id="mainContent">

    </div>
</section>

<?php include('../includes/overall/overallFooter.php'); ?>
```

**Page where content is taken from**

```
<?php include('../core/init.php'); ?>
<?php include('../core/db_connect.php'); ?>
<?php include('../core/init.php'); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Einsatz anlegen">
</form>
```

**Sidebar Navigation content**

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse" id="sidebarNavigationList">
        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
            <li><a href="" id="pageIncidents">Einsatzliste</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script correctly loads the content into the div "mainContent" as expected. This work fine. As soon as I hit the submit button the whole content in the div tags disappears. When I check with the Chrome dev tools the site structure, the tags are empty.

the php file does not contain any strange code to me that would call for that. I am relatively new to jQuery. How would I usefully check for an error or where should I start. I am not that experienced with debugging this.

Comment: In your **incidents.php** you wrote `include('../core/init.php');` twice, I don't know what there is in it but it can return an error, use `include_once()` so "if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again" from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/it/function.include-once.php)

Comment: thank you for this hint. I removed the second include. But still the content vanishes

Comment: Yes I know, I'm still loocking for a solution..

Comment: I am sorry Gersey. I didn't mean to be rude. I might have came across the wrong way. I appreciate your support very much

Comment: Consider using [`$.ajax()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) for a better control on the AJAX request

Comment: Nono, I don't speak english very well and I don't know how to be "kind" XD

Comment: I still do not see how this could go wrong, as the button does nothing at the moment

Comment: The button in your form does nothing because your form's `action` attribute is empty

Comment: Yes, I removed this action to check for the error. Which is quite more disturbing that after hitting a button that does nothing the content of the div element vanishes. When I click the link again in the sidebar menu, it appears again

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. I was completely on the wrong track. The whole setup is completely fine and the script works as expected. The issue is the form input type of "submit". Submit causes a complete reload of the page. As I have not set the initial display of the incidents page when loaded the first time, the whole form "disappears". Eventually it just reloaded the index.php. Changing the type to button solved the issue.